# How to insert data from MSSQL to MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I was select all data in table from SQL Server.

[This show imagine in my mind http://imgur.com/R4mkD9N](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrX6Z.png)

How to insert it into MySQL. Here I was get all data in SQL server.

```
    public DataTable chucvu_getlist()
    {
        string procname = "Select * from chucvu";
        DbAccessSQL db = new DbAccessSQL();    //use mssql
        db.CreateNewSqlCommand();
        return db.ExecuteDataTable(procname);
    }
```

But how to insert in MySQL from this database.
Usually, I was insert 1 table with code:

```
    public bool Insert()
    {
        DbAccessMySQL db = new DbAccessMySQL();           // this use MySQL
        db.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {
            db.CreateNewSqlCommand();
            db.AddParameter("@ID", ID);
            db.AddParameter("@Name", Name);
            db.ExecuteNonQueryWithTransaction("INSERT INTO chucvu(ID, Name) Values ('" + ID + "', '" + Name + "')");
            db.CommitTransaction();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

@Neil P, I was use SSIS to simple when fetching data in 2 database.

But when create import and export database, it have error is there:

I don't know how to fill in this textbox like DNS or ConnectionString

This error when select next button:

Is error imgur.com

Thanks.

Comment: You probably should look into bulk loading data, instead of reading / writing row by row.

Comment: How to do it? Normal, when copy from other table only: `SELECT * INTO ArchiveTable FROM MyTable` but 2 data server type is MySQL and MSSQL.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, you may want to look into using SSIS to copy data across. Using either the OLE or ODBC connectiors to read/write from MySql

Comment: @NeilP, I was update fail when use export and import using SSIS

Comment: It's DSN (Data source name), you give the name in ODBC settings and define the connection properties there. Maybe this helps: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-dsn-windows-5-2.html